# To receive data wirelessly by 3pi robot

Tags: 3pi, robotics, wireless

I want to interface a cc2500 module with the 3pi robot...How do i do that...I just have the cc2500 module(the one [here](http://thinklabs.in/shop/product_info.php?cPath=67&products_id=186))
I want my 3pi to move accordingly to the instruction given by another transciever.

Answer (score 2):

The board looks as though it has an AVR controlling the transceiver.

You need to interface the AVR on one transceiver board to the robot. You will then need to develop software for the AVRs on both units, to control the robot according to received commands, and to send commands via the transceiver on the second transceiver board.